# how to make html.editorfor unvisible in asp.net mvc 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to make my editor invisible? I got this but it is not working?

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(i => i.MyField),new { @visible = "false" })%>
```

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter to EditorFor method is not HtmlAttributes but it is additionalViewData. you have to write your own EditorTemplate if you want to use additionalViewData to set visibility or something else for that matter. Look at [this post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) to see how you can create custom editor templates
**Edit:** Supposing that Property MyField is of type string and you want to display it using text box, you have to create a partial view in EditorTemplates folder either in shared or any other view folder. in this view you can write something like

```
<%:Html.TextBox(string.Empty, Model, new{style = ViewData["style"]})%>
```

and in EditorFor method you can provide additionalViewData like

```
<%:Html.EditorFor(x=>x.MyField, new{style = "display:none;"})%>
```

Comment: excellent! do you have a quick code sample? i am a bit of a mvc beginner:(